# Find a specific word in a string Python

Tags: python, discord

I am making a Discord bot who reacts to certain words, the problem is that my bot reacts to a set of characters that match and not the word itself.

For example:

```
words = ["example1", "example2"]
for x in words:
    if x in message.content.lower():
         message.channel.send("yes")
```

My expected reactions:
1st message: example1    bot: "yes"
2nd message: aaaexample1aaa     bot: should do nothing but in reality the bot responds with: "yes"
3rd message: example1aaa  bot: should do nothing but in reality the bot responds with: "yes"

Comment: Do you want your bot to react if the message contains ONLY 'example1' ? Or if the message contains other words but with a separator it should work too ? Like for 'Hello example1'

Comment: `x in str` will be true if x is a substring of str. If you want those strings to be exactly equal, use an equality operator - `==`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try converting the string into an array and then just use the in keyword

it would be fast to cache the array, than calling it all the time

```py
words = ["example1", "example2"]
message_array = message.content.lower().split(' ')
for x in words:
    if x in message_array:
         message.channel.send("yes")
```

Comment: @Ebo if this helped you, and solved your issue, please mark this as the answer, thank you.

Comment: @Ebo look at this change, its faster and has greater performance

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to use regular expression directly. (`import re`)

In your code, you can change `if x in message.content.lower()` to `if x == message.content.lower()` to match the exact word.

Comment: It would be helpful for future viewers of the question, if you could provide a suitable explanation along with your solution, i.e. Why does the suggested change work? and how does it fix the problem presented in the OP, Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Your looking whitespace either side of your words?

As in...

```
words = [" example1 ", " example2 "] 
for x in words: if x in message.content.lower(): 
    message.channel.send("yes")
```

?

But, also looks like you've a leading string check to do too, so

```
words = ["example1", "example2"] 

msg = message.content.lower().translate({ord(i):None for i in ',.;'})  #Removing punctuation that would screw up line split - may or may not want to do that, in which case remove the .translate()
for word in words:    
    if word.center(len(word)+2) in msg \
    or msg[:len(word)+1] == word.ljust(len(word)+1) in msg:
        message.channel.send("yes")
```